# Is there a word to describe a phrase such as "it is what it is"

Tags: expressions

For example

> "it is what it is"

This multi-word statement has no real meaning if read literally (or at best a circular meaning), but it does express a meaning that is meta to its lexical meaning (a sense of helplessness and resignment).

Comment: Related: [“Everything is everything”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32149/everything-is-everything)

Comment: “C'est la guerre!” is similar.

Comment: I disagree with your assertion that it expresses "a meaning that is meta to its lexical meaning (a sense of helplessness and resignment)".  That assertion clutters up the question and makes it difficult to tell what, if anything, you are asking.

Comment: @jwpat lexical meaning: "the object of the statement is itself". Actual meaning (arguably): "a sense of helplessness and resignment". I use the term "meta" to indicate that the true meaning is more abstract than the lexical. Can you expand upon your disagreement?

Comment: ...although I agree with your assertion that it clutters the question. Perhaps the question was unclear in my mind when I asked it.

Comment: If you're not careful when you use a phrase like this, the most appropriate description becomes *trite*.

Comment: @OptimalCynic Agreed. The phrase comes to mind for me (and serves a purpose, I think) when asked a question regarding something that you perceive as problematic, but about which further in depth discussion would be undesireable (for example: for political reasons or courtesy).

Comment: I just wanted to record the best use (and anti-use) of this expression that I've ever encountered. From today's _[Oakland California] East Bay Times_, a basketball player talks about whether his acquisition by the Golden State Warriors is likely to lead to an extended stay on the team: "'That's the business of it. **It is what it is**," [D'Angelo] Russell] said. 'You just put yourself in a position to go somewhere a long period of time. **It may not be what it is** and that's the business. I've come to a realization of that and I understand that. ...'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean a word to describe that particular phrase?  Or phrases like that in general?

If the latter, then I might suggest *idiom*.

Comment: Of course, you're right. I suppose the use of idioms is so ingrained in the language I hadn't firmly grasped them as discrete terms of speech.

Answer (score 15):

You might describe the phrase as a [*tautology*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tautology) (of the logical variety, not to be confused with a rhetorical tautology). With this phrase in particular, since its function is to remind the speaker or listener of the nature of reality, you might call it a *meaningful tautology*.

Comment: More like ***semantic(al) tautology*** (cf. *rhetorical tautology*)

Answer (score -2):

*It is what it is* is nothing more than an expression often said not to overthink the obvious. If it walks like a duck, quacks like a duck, then it must be a duck. If a plumber is addressing a leak in a pipe, and there has been much rain the night before, it does not change the fact that the pipe is leaking. Except that what you are dealing with you must first look at at face value, then assess.

Comment: Welcome to English.se. There are some handy formatting tools that could make your answer a little easier to read.

Answer (score -2):

This sounds like an inverted pleonasm of, "What is it?", which is "What is it that it is?" in literal form.  "It is what it is" is a pointlessly redundant reply to the pleonasm, "What's that?".

Answer (score -2):

Everybody here takes everything so literally. I think the word for the phrase is "passive". You just let stuff happen. Apocalypse? Meh. It is what it is.

Comment: Hi Tyler. What is your reason for thinking the phrase is passive? Please expand on your answer with good reasoning.